# Problems with QGIS Plugin RasterAttributeTable / runtime error

Tags: qgis-plugins, raster-attribute-table

Initially the install of the plugin RasterAttributeTable lead to an error (Couldn't install plugin) but that seems resolved but still stuck with the runtime error and the plugin does not seem to be actually installed:

...
File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.9/site-packages/GDAL-3.3.2-py3.9-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/osgeo/gdal.py", line 4477, in OpenEx
return _gdal.OpenEx(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError:crs=EPSG:3857&format&type=xyz&url=https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs%3Ds%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=20&zmin=0: No such file or directory

I have reinstalled GDAL/GEOPANDAS, tried on the QGIS LTR version same result.

I am running iMac (i5) with ventura.

Comment: Okay resolved in part: I had a QMS Google layer in that same project that seemed to result in the specific error (and took me while to figure out where the mt1.google.com link was coming from). Removing that seemed to make things work again (after reloading).  Yet as soon as I have a google satellite layer in there the error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

So QMS or Openlayers seems to cause the error. Leave them out and it works fine. From the plugin developer at GITHUB: This plugin will be depreciated soon and the RAT becomes part of the QGIS core.